# N is infinite (a proof)

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

In the book *Introduction to Set Theory* (Third Edition, CRC Press, 1999), by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jeck, the following appears on page 70:

2.2 Lemma. -- If n ∈ N , then there is no one-to-one mapping of n onto a proper subset X ⊂ n. --

Soon after, comes the Corollary (2.3), which states:

(c) N is infinite.

Proof:

(c) by Exercise 2.3 in Chapter 3, the successor function is a one-to-one mapping of N onto its proper subset N - {0}.

Well... I don't understand that suggestion. The book does not previously present the theorem "If a set X is equipotent to the set Y and Y is a proper subset of X, then X is infinite".

Comment: What's the definition of infinite set that the book is using?

Comment: There are many equivalent characterization of infinite sets, which one do you know?

Comment: Could you please clarify what $n$ is in Lemma 2.2? Notationwise it appears both as an element of $N$, and a set (which has a subset $X$).

Comment: @DominikS Likely the natural numbers are built up as ordinals. Zero is the empty set, $1 = \{0\}$, $2 = \{0,1\}$, etc. Generally $n = \{0,1,...,n-1\}$.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, thank you!

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA  It seems to me that a theorem is implicit there:
"If A is equipotent to B, a∈ A, b ∈ B, then A - {a} is equipotent to B - {b}."

Answer (score 2):

It's a proof by contradiction.  Suppose $\mathbb N$ is not infinite.  Then it is finite.  By (2.3), it can admit no 1-1 map to a proper subset.  But the successor function is such a map.  This is a contradiction.  The contradiction establishes the fact that $\mathbb N$ is infinite.  I have no idea how to prove this in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: The book does not previously present the theorem "If a set X is equipotent to the set Y and Y is a proper subset of X, then X is infinite".

Answer (score 2):

By Exercise 2.3 in Chapter 3, the successor function is a one-to-one
mapping  of N onto its proper subset N - {0}.

In other words, N is equipotent to N - {0}.

If N were finite, then, by definition, N would be equipotent to a natural number n.

Thus:

n would be equipotent to N - {0} (transitivity of the equipotency relation) and, therefore, n U {n} would be equipotent to N. (*)

Thus, n would be equipotent to n U {n}, which contradicts Lemma 2.2.

(*) Here, I am resorting to a theorem not explicitly presented in the book:

```
 If A ~ B, a ∉ A, b ∉ B, then (A ∪ {a}) ~ (B ∪ {b}).
```

(A ~ B stands for A is equipotent to B.)